# On checkbox unchecked reset textbox value in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

On selecting File below checkbox gets enabled if checkbox is checked then the below password textbox gets enabled.

[image: Image1]

If the checkbox is unchecked the password textbox gets hide but the textbox value is not getting cleared.

[image: Image2]

```
$(function() {
  $('#<%=chkAddPdfPassword.ClientID %>').ready(
    function() {
      $('#<%=chkAddPdfPassword.ClientID%>').click(function() {
        if ($('#<%=chkAddPdfPassword.ClientID%>').is(":checked")) {
          $("#divPasswordField").show();
        } else {
          $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#txtFilePassword').val('');
          });
          $("#divPasswordField").hide();
        }
      })
    })
})
```

How can we do this with jQuery.

Comment: `$('#txtFilePassword').val('');` shouldn't be inside `ready` event.

Comment: Why don't you post an example html code snippet?

Comment: thanks i got the solution answer below posted

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the $(document).ready()

```
  $(function () {
        $('#<%=chkAddPdfPassword.ClientID %>').ready(
        function () { 
            $('#<%=chkAddPdfPassword.ClientID%>').click(function () {
                if ($('#<%=chkAddPdfPassword.ClientID%>').is(":checked")) {  
                    $("#divPasswordField").show();
                } else {            
                    $('#txtFilePassword').val('');
                    $("#divPasswordField").hide();
                }
            })
        })
    })
```

Comment: I tried this it doesnt work. but thanks for the efforts Answer posted above

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved : Solution

```
 <script> 
    $(function () {
        $('#<%=chkAddPdfPassword.ClientID %>').ready(
        function () { 
            $('#<%=chkAddPdfPassword.ClientID%>').click(function () {
                if ($('#<%=chkAddPdfPassword.ClientID%>').is(":checked")) {  
                    $("#divPasswordField").show();
                } else {
                    $("#divPasswordField").hide(); 
                     document.getElementById('<%= txtFilePassword.ClientID %>').value = '';
                } 
            })
        })
    }) 
</script>
```

Answer